# Is it possible to pass in array to a postgres query as a named parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have two tables with the following structures:

**T1**

| id | group_id | leaf_id | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 0 | bytes |

**T2**

| id | group_id | leaves | hashes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | {0, 1} | {} |
| 1 | 8 | {0} | {} |

I'd like to construct a query where I can find joined rows from these two tables where **T2**'s `leaves` column contains **T1**'s `leaf_id` column values.
This is what I got so far:

```
select * from Table2 t2
join Table1 t1 
on t1.id = t2.id 
and t1.group_id = t2.group_id 
and t1.leaf_id = any(t2.leaves);
```

This works as expected. However, I'd like to add an extra filter where only rows with certain `leaves` would be returned, like this for example:

```
select * from Table2 t2
join Table1 t1 
on t1.id = t2.id 
and t1.group_id = t2.group_id
and t1.leaf_id = any(t2.leaves)
and t2.leaves && array[8];
```

Is it possible to make this dynamic somehow? I wanted to use a named parameter like `:leafIds` but I just simply cannot construct an array of that.

Tried `:leafIds::int[]` or even `string_to_array` but not much luck. Thanks!

Comment: Using what Postgres driver?

Comment: `org.postgresql:postgresql driver 42.2.20`

Comment: Is that a Java dependency?

Comment: I'm using a DB manager (DBeaver) that's using this driver.

Comment: This works for me. What did you try, and what error do you get?  You said you tried :leafIds::int[], but where did you enter it?  This is a case where screen shots might be helpful.